# How to process this string?

Tags: html, linux, sed

I have html file containing texts like this:

```
<p>يورونيوز: <br />
&#8220; يقال إن للقمر تأثير كبير على نمو المزروعات، وأزهار الحدائق وخاصة النبيذ . &#8220; </p>
```

Now I want to remove 
 and concatenate two lines into one. How can I do this? I have to mention that “ is used for double quotation, which I replace it after concatenation.
I used this code, but it doesnt work:

```
sed -i -e '/<br \/>[ \r\t\n]+/d' 1.html
```

Answer (score 1):

`sed` reads content line by line, therefore you can't just remove '\n' character. It is not visible by `sed` by default.
You need first read append next line to pattern space and only after that you can delete `\n` character:

sed -e '/[\s]+$/{N;d}' 1.html

There is one thing I donn't understand: are you going to remove line with `<br>` and the next line? If so the code above is right.

Answer (score 0):

rush named correctly the reason why your code didn't work; this version does what you want.

```
sed -i '/<br \/>\s*$/{N;s/<br \/>\s*//}' 1.html
```